# Adobe Acrobat's markup and annotate trough LaTeX?

Tags: xetex, pdf, luatex, viewers, tools

Adobe Acrobat has the feature that enables the user to markup words or lines and to add an annotation to these markups. These features do not only exits in Acrobat.

The markup looks like this:

[image: Adobe Acrobat markup]

Is it possible to create with LaTeX/LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX a pdf that already has these markups (or even the annotations)?

To be honest I am not using annotation that much, but I use the marking of lines quite often and it is quite pedestrian to produce a pdf with LaTeX, to open it with Acrobat, to mark the relevant lines and then sadly to recognise an error, create the pdf again and have to markup again...

Comment: Have you considered just [highlighting the text?](http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-highlight-text-in-latex.html)

Comment: There is [pdfcomment](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment) which is already illustrated in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/how-to-annotate-pdf-files-generated-by-pdflatex)

Comment: Provided a `pdflatex` solution is also sufficient: some time ago, I wrote the `pdfmarginpar` package http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfmarginpar/doc/pdfmarginpar.pdf to get access to such annotation features. Might be superseded by pdfcomment as proposed by jfbu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use

```
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\hlt}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}
```

full

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\hlt}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}

\begin{document}

Text text \hlt{text} text

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I accepted this primarily because it seems to be the simplest solution. Another more elaborate alternative, as [jfbu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120436/adobe-acrobats-markup-and-annotate-trough-latex#comment268524_120436) pointed out in his comment, is the package [`pdfcomment`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment).

Comment: @ClintEastwood Yeah, I just saw that you accepted this and was thinking to myself "Did @jfbu ever get the ping?"  I may learn and write up an answer with `pdfcomment` for completeness, since that's *truly* a PDF annotation.