# Floating Information About Words

Tags: floating

it's possible to make a latex pdf , such that when the mouse points some word in the pdf, appears a floating information about it, like when we put the mouse over "Disco Local (D:)" and appears that information about the free space in the disk.

It's not necessarily for me use Latex, but there is a way to do it???

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: see e.g. the pdfcomment package.

Comment: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204151/make-notes-from-lyx-into-annotations-on-the-pdf) is about make that in LyX but also have examples in plain LaTeX.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the qiestion is unlikeley to be helpful for others.