# Interpret LaTeX comments as PDF's notes/annotations

Tags: comments, annotations

I want to know if it is possible to interpret LaTeX comments as PDF's notes/annotations.

I already know how to write annotations with PDFlatex. What I want to know is if it is possible to automate this process directly with LaTeX's comments.

So to have:

```latex
\chapter{Intégration}
\myCitation{Placé devant l'oeil, un doigt peut cacher l'immensité de l'horizon. Voir, c'est au contraire intégrer le détail dans un vaste ensemble.}{Arnaud \textsc{Desjardins}}
% my comment
% in multiline
Lors de la première semaine,
```

as:

[image]

Without doing anything more than that (well maybe a keyword to know which comment you want to show as annotation or not).

---

Thank you for reading,

if you ask why I want to do that, it is only to share work easily with a non-LaTeX fellow comrade. So he can open the PDF and quickly see what to do and where he needs to.

Hope you all have a good day!

Comment: Otherwise, I suppose we can create our own package interpreting comments and converting them using PDFlatex... Is there someone who already did it? I mean, it can easily fasten our productivity for review purposes... Hence I suppose I am not the first one to have this idea.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to convert comments into annotations, Why not just input them as annotations. Is your non-LaTeX comrade going to be editing the source document? If not then all the comrade needs is the annotations and the document creators can treat them as comments saying what is to be done. I presume that at some point all the annotations can be nullified.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204166/11604

Comment: @Fran That's surely the best option (I didn't know), well I wanted the comments for me to have the color syntax amist the annotations... at least it's better the PDFLatex (readable with more applications and the syntax is nicer). thank you