# Is there a better package to add comment / annotations into your LaTeX pdf than pdfcomment today?

Tags: comments, pdfcomment

I am aware of the [How to annotate PDF files generated by pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/how-to-annotate-pdf-files-generated-by-pdflatex) thread where the [pdfcomment](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pdfcomment.html) package is suggested. So this question is simply about whether you think this is still the best option for adding writing-up comments and self reminders as you go.

I just want to add notes here and there to remind myself to go back and finish up certain sections as I go through writing the next few sections. I quite like how the `Microsoft Word comments` look, is there something similar maybe?

Comment: You could use package `todonotes`. It gives you the possibility to add little boxes in your document, also a list of all if needed. Not a *comment* tough. \

Comment: That sounds like something useful I will try it out thank you.

Comment: To do notes did the trick I think we can put that as the answer and close this question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I just want to add notes here and there to remind myself to go back and finish up certain sections as I go through writing the next few sections.

Sounds like stuff you want *to do* later and add a note for yourself. Package `todonotes` helps you with exactly that task.

[image: fitzbanTodonotes]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\todo{Don't forget to put a real introduction here.}
\end{document}
```

The package can create a list of all notes for you. If the global option `disable` is used, no notes are printed. A lot more to discover in the documentation.  See `texdoc todonotes`.

Answer (score 4):

[image]
[Source](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/619-tip-of-the-week-add-inline-or-margin-comments-to-your-pdf)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\definecolor{a0}{rgb}{0.61, 0.77, 0.89}
\definecolor{a1}{rgb}{1.0, 0.75, 0.0}
\definecolor{a2}{rgb}{1.0, 0.74, 0.53}




\begin{document}

%\listoftodos

The coefficient of thermal expansion describes the change in relative dimensions of solids with temperature growing, and it is important characteristic of interatomic bonds features.
\todo[color=blue!40]{Todonote with a different color.}The coefficient of thermal expansion describes the change in relative dimensions of solids with temperature growing, and it is important characteristic of interatomic bonds features.

The coefficient of thermal expansion describes the change in relative dimensions of solids with temperature growing, and it is important characteristic of interatomic bonds features.
\todo[nolist]{Todonote that is only shown in the margin and not in
the list of todos.}%
The coefficient of thermal expansion describes the change in relative dimensions of\todo[size=\small, color=a1]{A note with a small fontsize.} solids with temperature growing, and it is important characteristic of interatomic bonds features.


\todo[inline]{testing testing}

The peculiarities of complex interatomic bonds in polar crystals are manifested precisely during their deformation under the scalar action, such as the uniform change in temperature\todo[noline]{A note with no line back to the text.}The peculiarities of complex interatomic bonds in polar crystals are manifested precisely during their deformation under the scalar action, such as the uniform change in temperature\todo[inline, color=red!50]{Inline todonotes.}The peculiarities of complex interatomic bonds in polar crystals are manifested precisely during their deformation under the scalar action, such as the uniform change in temperature\todo[inline, color=a2]{A note with no line back to the text.}%
The peculiarities of complex interatomic bonds in polar crystals are manifested precisely during their deformation under the scalar action, such as the uniform change in temperature. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello. Please make the document complete.

Comment: Sorry me, forgot, done.

Comment: I think your answer doesn't significantly add something new to the accepted one.

Comment: it complements the others