# texstudio commands \comment \alert and \add

Tags: texstudio

The new texstudio (4.0.1) added three new buttons to the top right of the tool bar.
When pressing them, the insert a `\alert{}`, `\comment{}{}` and a `\add{}` into the texfile.
However, compiling them results in an `Undefined control sequence. \comment` error.

What are these buttons supposed to do? And am I missing a package?

**Edit:**
As suggested in the comments, I have added a code sample here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    some crazy text what so ever \\
    $ a = b + c $
    
    \comment{and after the formula}{gg zz uu}
    \alert{some text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think some of these buttons should only be available when certain packages or classes are used. Maybe something went wrong there. At least alert seems to come from beamer.

Comment: @daleif Oh, ok that makes sense. I first thought that these are linked to the pdf mark-up things, where you can highlight text and add comments.

Comment: You should load the `easyReview` package for using these commands.

Comment: @hair-splitter Thanks, that's it!

Comment: What a bizarre addition without mention of anything to support it. Seems like one of the developers just "liked it." [Github](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1774).

Comment: @Werner That's actually kinda funny. But it would make more sense to me if these markups were compatible with the standard pdf annotation.

Comment: @Isotope: Yes. Or if the toolbar magically appeared once you added [`easyReview`](//ctan.org/pkg/easyReview) to your preamble. But just to be there, useable and cause failure without mention of a remedy seems to encourage problems. My suggestion would be to remove the Review toolbar because of this ad-hoc-ness.

Comment: @Werner I mean, they are not bad - but I can't even see the usecase for them. My humble suggestion would be to make them abbreviations for [``pdfcomment``](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment?lang=en), as seen in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/how-to-annotate-pdf-files-generated-by-pdflatex). This way also non-texuser on the receiving end of the pdf benefit from the change.

Comment: I see the new toolbar button after I upgrade texstudio to 4.1.1. A google search bring me here. easyReview package works, but should be mentioned somewhere in texstudio.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{easyReview} % for \comment, \alert, etc.
\usepackage{soulutf8} % for accented letters
\begin{document}
    \comment{and after the formula}{gg zz uu}
    \alert{some text őőőő}
\end{document}
```

Comment: interested in `easyReview`, I tried to do a test but it crashes with the `xcolor` library. is there a solution?

Comment: @Antonio: The `xcolor` package is loaded by `easyReview`, no need to reload.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. keeps giving me the same error over and over. i am using the book class