# What is the package of Texstudio proposals in the new version

Tags: packages, highlighting

In the new version of TexStudio we have some icons whose shapes are:

[image]

the commands are:

```
\alert{}    \comment{}{} \remove{} and so on.
```

But what is the package to use these commands. Because I am not able to make use of them in the raw format.

Comment: Duplicate question, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/619426/3929

Comment: Thank you so much. surprisingly I had searched items but I did not find this link you introduced. If I must delete this question please let me know.

Comment: I knew I'd seen it before. Just searched`texstudio comment`